# Editing comment in SO Android App resulted in escaped format

Tags: bug, comments, android-app, stack-overflow-app

When you edit a comment in the new Stack Overflow Android app, it converts non-alphanumeric characters into a special format upon opening the editing UI, but doesn't convert them back:

[image: example]

Comment: I was going to ask this exact question, but as it turns out this was asked already a year ago. Unfortunately there is no follow-up on this one, even though the fix is probably a one-liner, and in the current situation, it can make it very hard to modify a comment after you posted it. No bounties to give on Meta, it seems, so I hope that my edit and comment at least push this back into view.

Comment: @GolezTrol I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but ["The development on the mobile apps have been abandoned for more than a year."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373338/7795130) That answer comes from almost a year ago, so we're going on two years without any fixes being applied to the app. Good job on finding the existing bug report though instead of asking a duplicate. There's a [request to make the apps open-source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382780/7795130) and maintained by the community, and if that gets implemented, then maybe this bug will get attended to.