# Improve filtering/sorting in Android App

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Would welcome better question filtering and sorting options in the Android app.

For example, filter for questions with bounties, filter for unanswered questions with a specific tag (currently searching on a tag removes the unanswered filter), etc.

Likewise allow sorting with the specified filter remaining in place, such as by votes, date, reputation, random, etc.

Comment: This question is many-barreled. Feature requests ordinarily request one feature, not many (filter by multiple things, new sorts). I do agree many things should be improved in the Android app, but there have been some bugs that actively influence user experience ([this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351553/7296893) bothers me a lot) that haven't been fixed in over half a year. I doubt substantial improvement will get priority.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth true. In this case, I feel like the UI needs to be rethought to adequately support this change and having both of these elements in mind would help in doing the needed update.  It has been frustrating me long enough that I figured I should at least submit it. If it made a difference I could break it apart, but perhaps that would be better done in whatever bug tracker the app devs use, along whatever lines the devs find useful.