# Can the Stack Exchange app become open source?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

I still use this thing, mostly for notifications and quick replies to comments. There are a few long-standing bugs which I'm sure could be fixed very easily with community contributions.

What are the arguments against releasing it? I get that you may not have the resources to develop the thing, but surely someone could take a few minutes every now and then to approve a pull request and push an update to the App/Play store.

Comment: This is a great idea, the community could contribute a lot. The app has some bugs and they could be easily fixed by some contributions on github

Comment: But I don't think SE will do this because of the advertisements

Comment: I've never seen an advertisement in the app. Is that an Android thing?

Comment: Well I have seen a lot of advertisements in various android apps, and I think that SO will add advertisements to it's android application in future as the number of mobile users increase.

Comment: I think if they thought the number of mobile users were increasing, they would commit resources to the apps. I think it's not something they're interested in pursuing.

Comment: Even if mobile users are increasing, that's not necessarily an indicator that they'd decide to serve those users with a mobile app over simply making the website more mobile friendly (which they have been doing recently.) the mobile apps haven't had major updates in a really long time.

Comment: No matter how much they make the websites mobile friendly, a android native application is totally other thing in terms of usability and an UI friendly application. Although they have to expose several api's that do CRUD operations behind. They won't be comfortable doing it

Comment: BTW this was pretty recently asked on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315791/323179).

Comment: @Laurel nice, I always forget about Meta SE!

Comment: This question is asked many times 
 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315791/make-the-mobile-apps-open-source) [and here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230458/open-sourcing-stack-exchange-android-app/230639#230639) They have to do something about it

Comment: CRUD operations are already supported by the Stack Exchange API. The mobile apps are largely just a wrapper around that. @win

Comment: Maybe the other way around. If there is a public API, the community can build a mobile app around it, if it wants to.

Comment: My guess: you have to do a full code review before open-sourcing, and there's no-one to do the review since there are no Android devs anymore. While it may just use the API, you still want to verify that any secrets and oddities are removed.

Comment: @window.document You can already observe the mobile app's "internal" API calls by installing a root certificate on your device and MITMing Stack Exchange. Though that's not really necessary, since most of the "internal" APIs are documented somewhere on [meta.se].

Comment: @wizzwizz4 true. I even once tried to do it on another app very long ago but what about advertisements? It might happen that they are planning advertisements on the app this will prevent the app from getting open sourced

Comment: @window.document They've not changed the code for years. I doubt they'd start now.

Comment: As soon as the mobile users increase in number, they will try their best to put advertisements on their mobile applications. I doubt that it will be open sourced. @wizzwizz4

Comment: @window.document I doubt they'll put adverts in it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 can't blame a company for making profit

Comment: Why has nobody mentioned advertisements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've disappointedly tagged this as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), since that's been the official response from the team. Quoting Yaakov Ellis, a Stack Exchange developer, from [his answer on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315791/make-the-mobile-apps-open-source):

> We will not be making the mobile apps open source.
>
> To quote the answer given [the last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230639/51) that this question was
> asked:
>
> > The other 10% of the app however consists of internal things that we are not yet ready to put out to the world and say "here are all the
> > URLs, documentation, description of what they do, go wild". This
> > includes the server endpoints for the feed, user registration, etc.
> > Because of these, and the fact that the rest of the apps are simple
> > data-retrieval and demonstration, the mobile apps themselves are not
> > going to be open sourced.
>
> This reason is still relevant today.
>
> Unfortunately, we are not able to commit the significant amount of
> time needed to make a version of the codebase that would have these
> functions removed, and that would include code that is in a shape that
> we would be able to share. (Not to mention that were we to remove
> these pieces, the apps themselves would be completely unusable).